# Google Drive Mime Types

Tags: mime-types, google-drive-api

I am building an ios app which fetch files from google drive. When I get the result I need to filter them out. I need to figure out the exact MIME types supported here.

I found something in https://developers.google.com/drive/web/mime-types. But when I checked the actual result coming back from drive server, it has some differences. For eg. I expect MIME type of any picture to be "application/vnd.google-apps.photo" as per document. But in response I get "image/jpeg". Is this correctly documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page lists the Google-specific MimeTypes.  Any arbitrary non-Google MimeType is also possible.  You can see a list of common ones here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#List_of_common_media_types

Comment: Thanks. I am sure this will help me a lot!